# how to sense that the scheduled time by AlarmManager was passed in rebooting

Tags: android

for example,An AlarmManager to count numbers at 7AM using Calendar was set.

But user turns off the android at 6am and turns on 8am.
So program does'nt count.

I dont think i can avoid this situation if i reset AlarmManager on receiver of BOOT COMPLETED.

Please tell me the way to count exact number in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do a bit of work.  Save the time of your next alarm in permanent storage (file, shared preference, or database).  Whenever an alarm occurs, update this value.  Set a BOOT_COMPLETED listener.  When the boot completed listener launches, have it get the current time and check if its later than the time of the next alarm you stored.  If so, you missed it.  If not, you're ok.

Now if you have to worry about missing multiple alarms, it gets more complicated, but the idea is the same.